# Programmatically install windows services on remote machines using C#

Tags: c#, windows, service

I would like to programmatically install using a give AD user / delete / check  the status of a windows services using C#. I would need to constantly check the status of these dynamically created services from a remote machine.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Thank you.

Comment: this might help you http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sachin.nigam/InstallingWinServiceProgrammatically11262005061332AM/InstallingWinServiceProgrammatically.aspx

Comment: @Zain I'll try this, and update as soon as I have a result, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution provided in this threads suits my needs very well, and I have no issue in creating and managing remote services.

[Programmatically Install Windows Service On Remote Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481394/programmatically-install-windows-service-on-remote-machine)