# Is it possible to run and stop a task from windows service?

Tags: c#, service, task

I'm developing a page that it looks like a tasks console. We can modify configuration information in database in order to our Tasks created in another project and it will be a windows service run according to the configuration in database. But I wonder if I can start or stop these tasks from .aspx???? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out:
[How can I programmatically stop/start a windows service on a remote box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467367/how-can-i-programmatically-stop-start-a-windows-service-on-a-remote-box)

However I don't know if it would work with aspx, probably you will need some kind permissions